# Is AWS Parameter store throughput limit for per key or the whole service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store

I found the below limit AWS describes for Parameter Store.

```
Default throughput: 40 (Shared by the following API actions: GetParameter, GetParameters, GetParametersByPath)

Higher throughput: 100 (GetParametersByPath)

Higher throughput: 1000 (Shared by the following API actions: GetParameter and GetParameters)

For more information about Parameter Store throughput, see Increasing Parameter Store Throughput in the AWS Systems Manager User Guide.
```

I am wondering if the limit is for an individual key or the whole Parameter Store service(per account or region)

Comment: Where do you find these limits? I was not not able to find this info publicly.

Comment: @SushankDahiwadkar https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe throughput is the maximum number of transactions per second (TPS) that Parameter Store can process. So these limits are for the Parameter Store and not for the individual key.

Answer (score 1):

Based on current AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-throughput.html)

> Parameter Store throughput is set to use the default limit. The
> Parameter Store **throughput setting applies to the current AWS
> account and region**, which means **it applies to all AWS Identity and
> Access Management (IAM) users in this AWS account**. The throughput
> setting **applies to standard and advanced parameters.**

i.e. throughput limit is applicable to all the parameters of Parameter Store